# ngx-text-diff not updating when I dynamically add html attributes

Tags: angular

I'm using a npm package called ngx-text-diff to build a file content comparator, i successfully imported its component and it's working great, the html selector takes 2 arguments left and right which represent the 2 string to compare.
The problem is that i'm trying to dynamically change these attributes by letting the user chose 2 files from a list and then add their content to right and left but the text-diff component doesn't update and nothing happens.

```
        <td-ngx-text-diff id="textdiff" [attr.left]="selected[0]?.content" [attr.right]="selected[1]?.content"></td-ngx-text-diff>
```

Here is my function to add a file :

```
  add(selectedFile) {
    if(selectedFile != null || selectedFile != undefined)
    {
        if(this.selected.length < 2){
          this.selected.push({'content': selectedFile.content, 
          'path': selectedFile.path});
          const toastRef: NbToastRef = this.toastrService.success(`${selectedFile.path} successfuly added`);
      }
      else{
          const toastRef: NbToastRef = this.toastrService.danger("You already selected 2 files");
      }
    }
    console.log(this.selected)
  }
```

the html element is updating but it doesn't display anything :

[Html output with attributes added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljlQC.png)

View isn't updated :

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQoH0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

From ngx-diff [issue](https://github.com/ABenassi87/ngx-text-diff/issues/26):

> The component has an input called diffContent (observable type) that
>   you can use to refresh the comparison. The src folder of this project
>   you can see an example of how to use it. Each time that
>   this.changedText is updated you should to use this observer to update
>   the view.

```
<td-ngx-text-diff
          [left]="initialText"
          [right]="changedText"
          [diffContent]="contentObservable$"
        >
        </td-ngx-text-diff>
```

```
export interface DiffContent {
  leftContent: string;
  rightContent: string;
}
....
// Inside Component define observable
  contentObservable: Subject<DiffContent> = new Subject<DiffContent>();
  contentObservable$: Observable<DiffContent> = this.contentObservable.asObservable();

// Define a method that is called each time that `changedText` is updated:
 onChangedTextUpdated(textUpdated: string) {
  this.changedText = textUpdated;
  const newContent: DiffContent = {
    leftContent: this.initialText,
    rightContent: this.changedText
  };
  this.contentObservable.next(newContent);
}
```

---

Try to bind the attributes to component properties and update them instead of your list objects.

Additional you may update your length check? `if(this.selected.length <= 2){`

E.g.:

Html:

```
 <td-ngx-text-diff id="textdiff" [attr.left]="leftContent" [attr.right]="rightContent"></td-ngx-text-diff>
```

Component:

```
...

leftContent = '';
rightContent = '';

...
  add(selectedFile) {
    if(selectedFile) {
        if(this.selected.length <= 2){
          this.selected.push({'content': selectedFile.content, 
          'path': selectedFile.path});
          const toastRef: NbToastRef = this.toastrService.success(`${selectedFile.path} successfuly added`);
          if(this.selected[0]) {
             this.leftContent = this.selected[0].content;
          }
          if(this.selected.[1]) {
             this.rightContent = this.selectedFile[1].content;
          }
      }
      else{
          const toastRef: NbToastRef = this.toastrService.danger("You already selected 2 files");
      }
    }
    console.log(this.selected)
  }
```

Comment: Still not updating :/

Comment: Can you set up an Stackblitz to reproduce the error?